# h2 database - unable to create the table in h2 db in spring boot app

Tags: java, spring-boot, h2

I've added this spring boot dependencies in my project: web, jpa, h2

I went according this:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=min556C749k. got stuck after first test of database.

In short, there are 3 classes like:

```
@Entity
public class Post {
    @Id
    private int id;
}
```

and `application.properties`

```
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.datasource.platform=h2
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
```

I can access the `/h2-console` and able to successful test the db connection.

On connecting with the db, I can see there is no presence of the table.

**Note:** It's not like there is no data in the tables - there are no tables. Furthermore, there is no error pops up.

Since I'm here, how can I specify the type of column in h2 (like varchar with length of 525 in mysql)? Some special annotation?

Comment: Share the console logs.

Comment: I guess you need a Repository for each Entity

Comment: Share your code where you create and persist any entity. As this is an in-memory db probably all creation is postponed to the moment you "use" the db.

Comment: `and since im here`, this should be a new question. Anyway, read about the [@Column](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Column.html) annotation.